# Change background color of swipe-to-delete button

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to change the background color of the swipe-to-delete button to clear color. I have tried the following code, but to no avail:

```
UIView* myBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.editingAccessoryView = myBackgroundView;

cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are any color changes working at all?

Comment: Other colors worked. I'm going to use the color I'm using for the cell background. Thanks!